# customizing my android edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-button

I would like to customize my android edittext so that :

1. there would be a button at the end of the edittext
2. the button is in the range of the underline
3. the text entered would not exceed the button
4. ellipsize at the start of the edittext

So it would look like this, for example :

.̲.̲e̲d̲i̲t̲t̲e̲x̲t̲ ̲[̲b̲u̲t̲t̲o̲n̲]̲ ̲

instead of having the text go under the button

Comment: Most of what you are asking for just involve adding a button within a certain layout, probably horizontal.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: I tried to build a linear layout (orientation : horizontal)
this way, the underline part (with some animation as you click the edittext) would stop at the left of the button;
what i want is to let the underline also covers the button

Answer (score 0):

try this use EditText          `android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_calender"` to set icon in Edittext set max line property `android:maxLines="1"`

```
        <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_calender"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="tjhdshdhsdhjdhd"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**and you can also set it click listener like this**

```
 editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int DRAWABLE_LEFT = 0;
        final int DRAWABLE_TOP = 1;
        final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;
        final int DRAWABLE_BOTTOM = 3;

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getRawX() >= (editComment.getRight() - editComment.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {
                // your action here

             return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```